# Set DockPanel.Dock programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

How set DockPanel.Dock="Left" programmatically

```html
<RadioButton DockPanel.Dock="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="False" />
```

Answer (score 5):

give the radiobutton a name, and then try

```
DockPanel.SetDock(radioButtonName, Dock.Left);
```

Answer (score 2):

Xaml:

```
<RadioButton x:Name="radioButton" DockPanel.Dock="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="False" />
```

Code behind

```
radioButton.SetValue(DockPanel.DockProperty, DockStyle.Left);
```

This way can use to set other attached property